# typescript Iterable return type incorrect in "for of" context

Tags: typescript, iterable

Here is my code

```
interface A  {
    Id: string,
    Level: number,
    IA1: string,
    IA2: string,
    IA3: string,
    IA4: string,
}
interface B  {
    Id: string,
    Level: number,
    IA1: string,
    IA2: string,
    IA3: string,
}
interface C {
    Id: string,
    Level: number,
}
type Player = {
    A: Iterable<[A, number]>,
    B: Iterable<[B, number]>,
    C: Iterable<[C, number]>,
}
function find<T extends "A" | "B" | "C">(player: Player, type: T) {
    for(const [obj1] of player[type]){
    }
    let t1 : "A" | "B" | "C" = type as any
    for(const [obj2] of player[t1]){
    }
}
```

Here's playground link [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILOQbwFAYwSQBMAuZAZzClAHMAaXPAGQgDcIAbUkAVwFsAjaPTzJ8qAIykKVEHQYFUAJimUawvGIDMKmXJFiALDrXYAvtlCRYiFACEMOfSXKrZ6jMzadkPAUPmiEsZuAWLKLrrugdoRJuaW0PBIyADCWKHO0iYinhxcfIJQ9OZgAJ4ADigACuxwpdDIALzpIqik+FZw-OwQADwA2qi0PgXQALoAfFG27Z3dff22w76Fk1Eps9BdPQMpy6NQa2bYMNwgCGDAAPYgyDCghL0AKsgQAB6QIIRkyABEqL9kAAfP62QEg34pX4TAAU5Vq9SgpBqdSEyDKlVITwAlC08DArlAYQgbhRkP0rvwAFbiMbIK4wZDw1FQfoYiBjbGOPDmEQ9MDo8TIUj-cGgsWQwHNdnIOA-OAgUoBAlEkkgMkU6mKOkMpkI6Bs2lcgLmUxAA)

type obj1 [obj1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stXkO.png)
type obj2 [obj2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAoe1.png)

I thought the type of obj1 should be A | B | C, just like obj2, so where is it wrong?

Just don't understand, i want to know why

Comment: Observation: I don't understand the reasoning for using the generic constraint — and, without it, the yielded type from the iterator is what you expected: https://tsplay.dev/wRBpLw Can you clarify its purpose? (Another example: https://tsplay.dev/NV3nqm)

Comment: thanks for your reply, here's complete example, [tsplay.dev/w256xW](https://tsplay.dev/w256xW) The reason for using common constraints is that I want to reference this type

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382107/typescript-iterable-return-type-incorrect-in-for-of-context#comment133012387_75382107) Ok, that provides a partial explaination, but why not just do something like this? https://tsplay.dev/mbEkPN

Comment: This is a good way, The reason for not doing that is because other properties of player are accessed in the find function, At first, I just wanted to know why I couldn't do that, Now I will consider using the method you provide to bypass it

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382107/typescript-iterable-return-type-incorrect-in-for-of-context?noredirect=1#comment133013041_75382107) In that case, I can write an answer with something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3xzAW) that mimics the API of the more typical [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)? Does that answer your question, or am I still missing something?